# Fetching ListView Values

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-edittext

I have a listview with Textview and EditText in it. Now i want to fetch the value of that Textview and EditText I get the value of the TextView but not EditText. It gives me Blank value for the EditText.

Please Help Me

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount() ; i++) { 
    View v = adapter.getView(i, null, null); 
    ClassA obj = new ClassA (); 
    obj = (ClassA) v.getTag(); 
    String Text = obj.edittext1.getText().toString(); 
}
```

Comment: Please note EditText inputType is "numberdecimal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you set listener at the time editText is have no value.

Instead of it sent your editText to Listner and then extract value from editText.

```
 OnItemSelectedListener(new CustomListener(editText));

    public class CustomListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
    {
    private EditText editText;
    public CustomListener(EditText editText)
    {
    this.editText=editText;
    }

    onItemSelect(..)
    {
    Log.v("TAG",editText.getText().toString);

    }


}
```

in your main class add a

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTextList=new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

and a setter method to this editTextList

```
    public setEditTextList(EditText editText)
    {
    this.editTextList.add(editText);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     onClick()
{


for(EditText editText:editTextlist)
      {
       Log.v("TAG",editText.getText().toString());
      }

}


});
    }
```

In your adapter when one view is generated add your editText this view but to do that send a Main activity object in constructor.
Like

```
private MainActivity mainActivity;

CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity)
{
  this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
}
```

now after setting editView in your adapter

```
{


mainActivity.setEditTextList(holder.editText);





}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply...but I want to fetch every listitem on button click not on the OnItemSelectedListener()

Comment: is that button is listView item ?

Comment: no the button is outside of the listview.

Comment: Thank you Mohd for reply its really helpful to me..

Comment: welcome vote up if helpful thanks.